# onTouchListener is preventing onClickListener on "Oneplus X" and Xiaomi Mi devices

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have a simple view defined as

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/action_edit"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

I am trying to register onClick and onTouch events as follows.

```
    mEditButton = view.findViewById(R.id.action_edit);
    mEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction_Item_Edit_Button_Clicked(mItem);
            }
        }
    });

    mEditButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ith.startDrag(EditTextViewHolder.this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This was working fine in emulator, Lenovo A6000+ (Lollipop), Moto X Play(Marshmallow). But when I try to run the app on **Oneplus X** (Marshmallow) and **Xiaomi Mi** devices onClickListener is not getting fired. When I remove onTouchListener then onClickListener is working. Some how onTouchListener is consuming event even though I am returning 'false'.

I tried including following attributes for the view but no luck.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I tried replacing **View** with **Button**, **ImageButton** but no luck. Is it some kind of bug with said devices or am I doing something wrong here? I don't understand how come its working in other devices and emulator but not in said devices.

If there is no way of rectifying this problem can somebody suggest an alternative to it like using only onTouchListener to detect clicks as well as swipe gestures?

I tried all the related questions in SO and none of them worked for me, So I am posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect click event with `onTouchListener` in this way:

```
mEditButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
            private long startClickTime;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                        if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                            //click event has occurred
                        }
                    }
               }    
               return true;   
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use only onTouch event.

To distinguish a single tap with something else, you can use the `GestureDetector`.

You could try with something like this:

```
GestureDetector gDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTap());
mEditButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        if (gDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            // single tap happened
            return true;
        } else {
            // your code for move and drag or everything else
        }

        return false;
    }
});

private class SingleTap extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can find more info and a tutorial on the Android Developer site [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)